# Why does the code not work?

Tags: number-theory, sagemath

I want to write a program which gives me all prime ideals in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K $,  $K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-5})$ . They should have the property to be principal.  My problem is that the condition if(J.gens()[0]-1 in L):
does not really work. By this I want that the generator of the principal ideal minus $1$ is contained in the ideal L.

```
   sage: K.<a> = QuadraticField(-5)
             cl = K.class_group()
              g = cl.gens()[0]
               L=K.fractional_ideal(-a-1)
    sage: for norm, ideals in K.ideals_of_bdd_norm(10).items():
             for J in ideals:
                 if (J.is_prime()):
                   if  (cl(J)==g^4):
                     if(J.gens()[0]-1 in L):
                         print norm,J
```

Comment: I cannot agree with the close vote.  The help center specifically says you can ask about "software that mathematicians use."  Remind me again, who uses Sage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [answered](https://ask.sagemath.org/question/51834/why-does-the-code-not-work/) this on *Ask SageMath*:

> What you are looking for is `J.gens_reduced()` instead of `J.gens()`.

See the [documentation of `gens_reduced`](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/number_fields/sage/rings/number_field/number_field_ideal.html#sage.rings.number_field.number_field_ideal.NumberFieldIdeal.gens_reduced):

> Express this ideal in terms of at most two generators, and one if possible.

By contrast, `gens()` are just the generators which were given when the ideal was constructed (in this case, by Sage).